# How do I add custom icons to custom Ribbon tab in Word?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, ms-word, add-in, shared

I am trying to add custom icons to a **Shared Add-in** for Microsoft Word. The **Shared Add-in** uses  XML to add a tab to Word's Ribbon.

I am following the guidance of this document on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb462634.aspx): I have followed the steps described in the document for adding the image as a Resource. When I run the installer, and open Word the icons do not show up.

Also, I am getting a **Cannot register assembly /file-path/ access denied. Please make sure you are running the application as Administrator. Access to the registry key HKEY_ClASSES_ROOT/RibbonTest.Connect is denied.**

There is only one user on my windows install and it is Admin, so I am not sure what this means.

Does anyone know what might be going on?

For reference sake,I am writing the code on Windows 7 in VS Studio 2008 for Word 2007

Comment: Are you right clicking, **Run as Administrator**?

Comment: I am using the installer that is added when you create the project in Visual Studio. I have not **Run as Adminsistrator**. The account I am using is an admin account.

Comment: I solved my image issue. It turns out that large menus require a 64 x 64 pixel icon. Buttons require 16 x 16 pixels.

I am still not sure about the registry key issue.

Comment: Great, you can answer the question in a "Your Answer" below and then accept your own answer (with the check mark) as this will then remove this question from the "unanswered" list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The various different buttons types require different image sizes. Large buttons use a 32 x 32 pixel image for example.Small buttons work with images starting at 16 x 16.

If an image is too small, it won't show up in the ribbon.

See this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd316921%28VS.85%29.aspx#sizes) for more detail. The two attributes you need to keep in mind are **strong image** and **size**. Make the size of the image matches the size of the control. There is a table in the MSDN article which should make this more clear.